# a c# class that contain all json properties of google maps api

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net, maps

ok, so I am trying to use `JSON.net` to purse the JSON string of google maps API to an object:

```cs
string url = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=75+9th+Ave+New+York,+NY&destination=MetLife+Stadium+1+MetLife+Stadium+Dr+East+Rutherford,+NJ+07073&key=YOUR_API_KEY";

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);

            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            response.Close();

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseFromServer);
                                                       ^
                                                       |
                                                      here
```

and I need to replace the `T` with the object that contains all the JSON fields example:

```cs
class ex
{
int[] arr;
string str;
(....)
}
```

however, the JSON string that returned from google maps API is very long and contains many fields, and as I'm pretty new to JSON, I will probably get this wrong. I wonder if there is a way to auto-generate a class to contain all these properties (maybe anonymous types, somehow?) or if someone did this class before me and open-sourced it?

thank you in advance!

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/ is something you could use

Comment: @JReno is this magic 0: